# master's degree vs master degree

Tags: punctuation

Could you please tell me which one is correct, `master's degree` or `master degree`?

I am writing in this context

```
....of the college in which I will have completed Master degree
```

#### Also

Do you write *Master* with a capital letter or *master* with a lower case letter?

Comment: Related: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3638/is-there-an-apostrophe-in-a-masters-degree and http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/94123/masters-degree-capital-m-or-not .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Master's degree* is correct: it is a degree that is held by a master, someone who has mastered a discipline. (We don't use the word *master* as a title that way anymore, but the older usage survives in *master's degree*.)

You should use a lowercase *m* unless the word appears at the beginning of a sentence.

Comment: Also, if you're taking about specifics of your degree then you would capitalize the M: Master of Arts in Underwater Basketweaving, or Master of Science in Beancounting, for example.